# Is it possible to add custom background image for carousels on Google Assistant Actions?

Tags: themes, actions-on-google

I am developing an action for Google Assistant and I want to know what I can on Smart Displays. In Google's own video, upon user input, the app shows carousels and if the user clicks any one of the carousel items, a new screen with a different background image opens.

When I dug in to see how we can do that, all I could find was a single general background image in the app setting. So my question is how can I change the background image depending on the user-input?

[image: The carousels displayed after the user input]
[image: Custom background after clicking the carousel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's styling options (incl. background image) for Actions on Google can be found in the Theme customization tab in the Actions on Google console. Please note that if you define a theme for your project, **rich responses across your project's Actions will be styled according to your theme**.

Background image will use a custom image in place of the background color. You'll need to provide two different images for when the surface device is in landscape or portrait mode, respectively.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses